# d3-sankey from hierarchical data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hierarchical-data, sankey-diagram

I am practicing to generate Sankey diagram from hierarchical data instead of nodes and links objects.
Here is example data (Same Object modeling for generating forceDirectedGraph from hierarchical data)

```
const _data = {
  name: "Company",
  children: [
    {
      name: "Tech",
      children: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Zeynep",
          position: "Manager",
          value: 3
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Ahmet",
          position: "Intern",
          value: 25
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Mehmet",
          position: "Web Developer",
          value: 2
        },
      ],
      value: 6
    },
    {
      name: "Finance",
      children: [
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "Cem",
          position: "Manager",
          value: 2
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          name: "Ezgi",
          position: "Junior Researcher",
          value: 15
        },
        {
          id: 8,
          name: "Aleyna",
          position: "Accountant",
          value: 2
        },
      ],
      value: 3
    },
    {
      name: "HR",
      children: [
        {
          id: 11,
          name: "Elif",
          position: "Manager",
          value: 4
        },
        {
          id: 12,
          name: "Naz",
          position: "Recruiter",
          value: 5
        },
        {
          id: 13,
          name: "Gamze",
          position: "Analyst",
          value: 5
        },
      ],
      value: 1
    }
  ],
  value: 1
}
```

I searched for it but couldn't find any solutions or examples. Have anyone ever tried to do something like this before ? especially using d3.hierarchy.

Any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated a lot,
Thanks